# Leaflet - change map color

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to style a leaflet map like this (water: grey; land: yellow;) ?
I was not able to find a reference in the docs. http://leafletjs.com/features.html

If yes, is it easy like with google maps or do I have to color the polygons representing land and water somehow?

I'd like to benefit from leaflet's infowindows but I have to style the map like this.

[image]

Comment: This is an old post, but I came upon this by google search;

How about css filters? Would that hurt the c/g pu a lot? You could in theory modify the way the map looks. e.g. do this for a dark mode to save battery life of a mobile device (oled?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way would be do this by adding them as Polygons by Leaflet's `L.GeoJSON`. First you would need to find a proper dataset of the world's boundaries. I found one here: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json Save the `world.geo.json` file so you can use it one your own server. Now initialize a simple map:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0,
    'layers': [
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
        })
    ]
});
```

Fetch the GeoJSON file using your favorite XHR library (i'm using jQuery in this example) and then use the data to initialize a GeoJSON layer, and do some styling:

```
$.getJSON('world.geo.json', function (geojson) { // load file
    L.geoJson(geojson, { // initialize layer with data
        style: function (feature) { // Style option
            return {
                'weight': 1,
                'color': 'black',
                'fillColor': 'yellow'
            }
        }
    }).addTo(map); // Add layer to map
});
```

That's it, can't make it any simpler. Here's a working example on Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UGQ9xt?p=preview

(note that i load the GeoJSON file directly via Gitraw/Github, but you're not supposed to do that in a production site)

And here's the reference for `L.GeoJSON`:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson

Edit: Other options are more complicated but do not have some of the drawbacks you mentioned in the comments, here are the best i can think of:

Using a combination of Leaflet and the awesome [D3](http://d3js.org/) library by Mike Bostock. Here's a quick example: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/ It doesn't suffer from the redraw on pan but it's harder to grasp.

Another solution is using [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) They have a tool called [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) which allows you to generate your own tilesets. That would be the perfect solution, it wouldn't have any of the mentioned drawbacks and you can style almost everything. Only drawback is that you'll need to host to tiles yourself.

Comment: Your solution indeed is simple, thanks. Allthough there are some drawbacks like borders that are not exactly matching the outlines (could be better with a more precise dataset) or the polygons not updating on panning until mouseup. Unfortunately the client is very excited about the color change and is likely to brag about the drawbacks mentioned.

Comment: A more precise dataset is indeed the solution, i was just demonstrating. It will get larger so it's a longer load but that could be solved by converting your dataset to [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) and coverting it back on the client. There are other options that use Leaflet, i'll add them to my answer. And no thanks, you're always welcome, this is what SO is for. Just accept the answer if it's a solution to your problem so that others with the same problem can find an approved solution too.

Comment: @iH8 +1up for mentioning TileMill. Works great

Comment: I'm attempting to change the color of water but in vain. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: plunker is gone :(

Answer (score 4):

To add to the answer @iH8 gave:

I've used [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) with [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) to customise a pretty basic world map and it looked great. It was really easy to work with. It also supports the use of shape files- if you are so inclined.

[image: TileMill example]

Here is the .mss you can start to fidget around with to get close to the colour scheme you want:

```
Map {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#countries {
  ::outline {
    line-color: #000000;
    line-width: 2;
    line-join: round;
  }
  polygon-fill: #ffce0c;
}
```

After making your beautiful map you can generate the MBtiles and serve it with TileStache.

Here is a [tut](https://milkator.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/do-some-first-experiments-with-tilestache/) on using TileStache.
Hope that helps!

Comment: The page is already online, but thank you for the input. It may be useful for future projects.